# Using LINQ to query XML file

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an XML document that looks like this. It has been created using the Diagram feature of DevExpress.

```
<XtraSerializer version="17.1.3.0">
   <Items>
     <Item1 ItemKind="DiagramRoot">
       <Children>
         <Item1  Shape="Triangle" Content="AA" /> 
         <Item2  Shape="Triangle" Content="AB" /> 
         <Item3  Shape="Octagon"  Content="A"  /> 
       </Children>
     </Item1>
   </Items>
 </XtraSerializer>
```

I would like to Query it to return the *Shape* and *Content* of all items under *Children*. I tried the query below but it does not work.

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load("C:\\Users\\Jb\\Desktop\\Network_Base.xml");

var items = from r in document.Descendants("Children")
            select new
            {
                Content = r.Attribute("Content").Value,
                Shape = r.Attribute("Shape").Value,
            };

foreach (var r in items)
{               
    Console.WriteLine(r.Content + r.Shape);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following :

```
var results = doc.Descendants("Children").FirstOrDefault().Elements()
                 .Where(x => x.Attribute("Content") != null).Select(r => new {
                     Content = r.Attribute("Content").Value,
                     Shape = r.Attribute("Shape").Value
                 }).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your help. Unfortunately it didn't work. I get an error when the query is executed.

Comment: I tested it as well.  It works.  Is your xml different than what you posted?

Comment: I tested it with the posted code before posting and did not get any errors.  Add picture of results

Comment: Actually you are right, it works, i made stupid mistake, thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi again. If my xml file has another item like this:  <Item4  Shape="Arrow"  Start="AA" End="A"  /> . The query you gave does not work since item4 does not have the same Attribute as the others. How can I exclude item4 from the query?

Comment: See changes.  Added WHERE.